# Canceling a Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-parallel-for-or-foreach-loop), I have this piece of code. But it doesn't work as intended. The loop stops without hiting the cancellation key when it's finish. No key press or console.write in the new task is displayed.

Console ouput, debug trace explainned:

```
Press any key to start. Press 'c' to cancel.    <-- Starting
.                                               <-- Key pressed

<Multiple line of result>                       <-- Parallel.ForEach ouput
(...)
</Multiple line of result>

Canceled                                        <-- Hit finally Parallel.ForEach over
END! Press a key                                <-- Program
```

What I expected was: Starting a thread waiting for a specific key. If anything else than this specific key is hit, prompt for specific.

What I did:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test();
}
static void test()
{
    int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToArray();
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // Use ParallelOptions instance to store the CancellationToken
    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
    po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
    po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
    po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start. Press 'c' to cancel.");
    Console.ReadKey();

    // Run a task so that we can cancel from another thread.
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cancellation..");
                cts.Cancel();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress 'c' to cancel.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("task ..");
    });

    try
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(nums, po, (num) =>
        {
            double d = Math.Sqrt(num);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} on {1}", d, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {  // perhaps an exception that was not expected? 
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cts.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("END! Press a key");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

99% msdn code, minor edit for trace, trying to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You are missing a in line, it's in the MSDN code:</s>

```
Parallel.ForEach(nums, po, (num) =>
{

     //add this one, it is to cancel it.
     //UPDATE: this isn't actually needed
     //po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
 });
```

And, your while loop exits prematurely. You should remove the `Console.KeyAvailable` line.

Also note that the `Console.ReadKey()` is blocking the loop.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
      Console.WriteLine("\nPress 'c' to cancel.");
       if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
       {
             Console.WriteLine("Cancellation..");
             cts.Cancel();
       }
 });
```

As alternative, if you want the same flow, you could use:

```
 while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
```

In that case, taken from [this msdn example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Console.KeyAvailable);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2), it should be like:

```
while (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
     Thread.Sleep(250); // Loop until input is entered.

cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
Console.WriteLine("You pressed the '{0}' key.", cki.Key);
```

Note: the `Sleep` is there to not overload your CPU.

---

Full working code: (note: no sleep applied and the `Press 'c' to cancel` isn't displayed in in such a way that you can actually see it, IMO you should just leave out the `while (!Console.KeyAvailable)` part.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp15
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test();
        }
        static void test()
        {
            int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).ToArray();
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // Use ParallelOptions instance to store the CancellationToken
            ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
            po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
            po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
            po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start. Press 'c' to cancel.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // Run a task so that we can cancel from another thread.
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 'c' to cancel.");
                    }

                    if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cancellation..");
                        cts.Cancel();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("task ..");
            });

            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(nums, po, (num) =>
                {
                    double d = Math.Sqrt(num);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} on {1}", d, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                    po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                });
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {  // perhaps an exception that was not expected? 
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cts.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("END! Press a key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy past msdn again, Run it .. still doesnt work. Is that a no repro for you?

Comment: ... I just tested without the `ThrowIfCancelRequested`, it also seems to cancel the loop correctly.

Comment: Ok. So, msdn code work if the first key that you press is `c`. when they say: "Press any key to start. Press 'c' to cancel." it mean any try to cancel pressing c after this is useless. An my try to use `while (Console.KeyAvailable)` was doom because of the heavy `Console.WriteLine` in the `ForEach`, `Console.KeyAvailable` sometimes return false. Thanks for you code,